# Next.js Metadata Object inside pages folder

Tags: next.js, metadata

Is it possible to use the new Next.js Metadata Object not inside the new app routing structure but inside the pages folder, i.e. the routing structure before Next 13.*

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: No, it is not possible to use this feature within the pages directory.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance to Youssouf and Fabios answer, it is not possible.